# MySQL: Joining menu table, user table, access table

Tags: mysql, join

Well guys, I have three tables here, menu, user and access. For simplifying let's consider:

- User table has one column: id
- Menu table has 5 columns: id, title,
  url, lft, rgt
- Access table has 4 colums: id,
  user_id, menu_id, access

I'm using SitePoint's [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2) to display the menu:

```
SELECT id, title, lft, rgt, url FROM menu WHERE lft BETWEEN 3 AND 49 ORDER BY lft ASC;
```

In the access table, the access column is having values of 0 or 1. At the same time, on a given page, I have the id value of User table, say $id.

The idea is modify the above select to show only those menu items, where in the corresponding Access table, the access column is set to 1. Where access = 0, the menu doesn't turn up for the given user.

Have I been clear? Thanks in advance for any help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select id, title, lft, rgt, url from menu join access on (menu.id = access.menu_id) where (lft between 3 and 49) and access.access=1 order by lft asc;

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM menu AS s JOIN access AS r ON s.id = r.menu_id         WHERE s.lft BETWEEN 3 AND 49 AND r.access > 0 AND r.user_id = $id         GROUP BY s.id ORDER BY s.lft ASC` Thanks John, this works with a group by, perfect. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ...
From menu
Where lft Between 3 And 49
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From AccessTable As T1
                Where T1.menu_id = menu.Id
                    And T1.access = 1
                    And T1.user_id = $id
                )
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, while it's a working query, I found that John's solution was somewhat faster. I thank you for your help. Cheers.